# How create bash file to launch Java program with VM Arguments

Tags: java, javafx, runtime-error, jvm-arguments

I need to create a shell script file to run my Java program. This program contains VM Arguments hence my question.

For the moment here is what I tried:

```
#!bin/bash

# VM Arguments 
set vmargs1 = "--module-path $/home/User/Desktop/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml"

java -jar /home/User/Desktop/Test.jar echo $vmargs1
```

But the application does not launch and here is the error message:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class application.Main
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application
```

This message indicates that the VM Arguments were not taken into account when launching the application.

I also tried without the `echo` to see if it worked but nothing either.

How can I make it work properly?

Comment: VM parameters are passed BEFORE the jar file. Otherwise, they are treated as application parameters,

Comment: Further, there shouldn't be a dollar sign between `--module-path` and `/home/User/Desktop/...` and neither an "`echo`" in the middle of the command line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All arguments before either `-jar jarfile` or `main.class.name` are args for the VM. All arguments that follow are args for the application.

You are passing the VM args to your app. Move the `$vmargs` to the front.

Comment: So I need to write : `java $vmargs1 -jar /home/User/Desktop/Test.jar` ??